# How to update authentication in auditorAware

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
    public class JpaAuditingConfiguration {
    
      @Bean
      @Scope(value= ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
      public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {

        Authentication authentication 
             = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return () -> Optional.<String>empty();
        }
        return () -> Optional.of(authentication.getName());
      }
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaAuditingConfiguration.class, args);
      }
    }
```

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      @Autowired
      private UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;

      @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
                               throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
             .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout/success")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                // Filter for the api/login requests
                .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", 
                                     authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // Filter for other requests to check JWT in header
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(), 
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        
    }
```

```
    public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                           ServletResponse response, 
                           FilterChain filterChain) 
                           throws IOException, ServletException {
       Authentication authentication 
        = AuthenticationService
                  .getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest)request);
    
       SecurityContext securityContext 
                    = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
       securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    }
```

`auditorProvider` seems to be called only once when application starts. `authentication` is called before it is set in `doFilter`. `authentication` object is always null and doesn't update when it's set later in `doFilter`. When I update a row in db, `createdBy` and `lastModifiedBy` are always null.

My `doFilter` seems to be called when an HTTP request is processed.

I followed a tutorial to learn spring security, but after troubleshooting for a few hours and followed through many similar tutorial, still can't figure out how to properly set the authentication in sequence so when I update a row, spring will update `lastModifiedBy` and `createdBy` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your issue is that you are creating an anonymous `AuditorAware` but you are evaluating the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` outside the body so whatever at that creation time will be kept inside the body.

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(value= ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {

        return () -> {
            Authentication authentication 
                    = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            return Optional.ofNullable(authentication)
                    .map(Authentication::getName);
        };
    }
```

- You could say, you have `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` but it is useless if it was autowired into a singleton instance that framework uses.

Comment: just tested, works, finally...thanks for the help. Sorry if this sound like a stupid question, i'm still learning, can you please explain what this line is doing? `Optional.ofNullable(authentication).map(Authentication::getName);`  my interpretation after a quick google search is that when `authentication` is not null, it will call getName method, but when will it be not null? did you turn the return statement into a data stream? how? really appreciate your help

Comment: Just assume your return is just this `return Optional.ofNullable(authentication);` and this is equivalent to `if (authentication == null) return Optional.empty() else return Optional.of(authentication);`  but then you can chain operations after it as well like in the answer, it will not execute the rest of the chain if it is already `empty`